# Regarding interaction with metal sword and white gas

Tags: metal, fuel

I have a large sword that is comprised of over 1000 layers of Titanium and High Carbon Steel. I wrapped it in Kevlar Wick and I set it on fire using Coleman White Gas (Camp Fuel) for performances. What I want to do is keep my sword in a tube or PVC pipe that has a reservoir of the white gas liquid fuel I use.

My question: will I harm my sword if I let it sit in the liquid gas for a long time?

Comment: What is in white gas?

Comment: This seems a very broad question, <joke>I do wounder if it is broadsword</joke>

Comment: It wont harm it more the putting on fire, which unless you're some kind of Thoros of Myr, isn't particularly good idea.

Comment: I certainly appreciate the joke, sorry for the vagueness of my question. This is a link to the exact fuel I have that I want to keep my sword with wick submerged in.

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Crown-Camp-Fuel-Gallon/51741744

Comment: also when it is on fire, the metal doesn't get hot at all. the wick is heat resistant and you swing the sword around, preventing it from heating even the wick. After the flame extinguishes you can immediately put your hand on the wick and feel only a gentle warmth

Comment: what I really was looking for specifically was if the liquid gas would begin to break down, structurally weaken the integrity of, or corrode my steel/titanium metal sword. if there is any more information I could provide I would be happy to try my hardest

Comment: I have looked at the fuel, it looks like some version of gasoline (US) or petrol (UK) which is for some special camp stoves. I wounder how the heating of the sword in the fire display will be any worse than the heating of the sword in a furnace during the forging will be. I am glad the OP liked the joke.

Comment: So from what I know about my fuel, is that it is different from lamp oil in the sense that my fuel burns brighter, bigger, and for less time than lamp oil would. When you use this fuel and wick the fire obviously is hot, but like I stated earlier when you swing the sword and keep the fire in motion it never actually get the sword or even the wick hot. it has a gentle warmth to it and when the flame is extinguished you can put your hands on it. The sword itself is wrapped in several layers of wick, and I am to reaching out to see if anyone knew if the gas would corrode the metal over time

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1031670893591597&set=a.105886432836719.12383.100002460889705&type=3&theater

Comment: If it is similar to gasoline i.e. just a mixture of alkanes, then I cannot see how it can break down to form something that will damage the metal surface. If anything it will be protective because you're going to want to keep water away from the surface

Comment: on the back of the can of fuel it does say it has properties added to prevent corrosion, so I would certainly think it would be safe, but I planned to have the blade and wick submerged in an airtight sheathe that would contain fuel, and it would be covered in liquid gas indefinitely until I unsheathe it and light the sword

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the fuel will harm your sword. The metal won't react with the fuel.

Does your sword have any parts that aren't metal though? If there's any plastic, leather, fabric etc. then those could be dissolved or harmed by the fuel. I also don't know what will happen to your Kevlar wick if it's left in camp fuel for a long time. It might contain softeners or other chemicals that might leach out.

Most importantly, I am not comfortable with your tube or PVC pipe that has a reservoir of white gas in it. Camp fuel is flammable, and if you get a leak and it evaporates and mixes with air, it's quite possible to fill a car with an explosive mix. ([Link to 1st search result on Youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BC7k4QwSU7E)) I know this sounds like a prosaic concern, but fire is dangerous, and I'm pretty sure more people get injured or die from stupid accidents with flammable substances than swords.

Please keep your fuel in a suitable, dedicated container. Read and follow the warnings on the container that your fuel comes in. Respect fire.

Comment: The tube/PVC pipe was just an example. I will be doing more research before I ever put the idea to practice and make a perfectly sealed (blade in and when the sword is out and I am performing) container and test it with other liquids before the white gas, then put the gas in the container and let it sit for a while, move it into different positions here and there, and make sure my container doesn't leak or degrade. I am no fool, I will take every reasonable precaution and test as much for as long as I can before I dedicate this idea into practice. Thank you so very much for your assistance